# iOS: manually delete Caches directory on iPad

Tags: ios5

As iOS 5.0 guidelines require to store downloadable content in "Library/Caches" directory instead of "Documents", I wonder if it's possible for end-user (or QA team) to delete manually these caches on IPad (to check the application's behavior when Caches are absent)?
Or can I only purge Caches programmatically?